# Updated Android Studio to 3.0 and getting this issue

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':App:mergeDebugResources'.
    > There were multiple failures while executing work items
       > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$FileGenerationWorkAction
          > Error while processing /media/nikhilesh/App/src/main/res/drawable/ic_add_black_24dp.xml : Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/green": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.
```

How can we solve this?

Comment: Try cleaning the project and rebuildit

Comment: Related thread for later part of the error text which is present in the logs - [References to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46978566/465053)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can add the following line inside your default config of your app build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig{
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Edit: you also need to add this dependency if you didn't already

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

**Update:**

Since Gradle 3.4 the `compile` configuration is [deprecated and should be replaced](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#new_configurations) by `implementation`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem is because the new gradle cannot refer to color library, which you use to get the @color/green value.

The solution is same as [rotemitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150798/rotemitz) said
Just add this line to your defaultConfig of build.gradle (Module : app)

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

AND to dependencies of the same build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

Note : You may change the appcompat version, refer to your compile SDK version

Answer (score 7):

> You just need to add the following line inside your default config of your app
>   build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig{
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```