# References to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation

Tags: android, resources, android-studio-3.0

AndroidStudio 3.0 / Android Gradle plugin 3.0

```
<vector>
  <path android:fillColor="@color/image_button_disabled"/>
</vector>
```

I get this error:

> references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation

Will it be possible to resolve it or is it a deprecated solution?

Comment: Related thread - [Updated Android Studio to 3.0 and getting this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46947008/465053). Though solution is exactly same.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

To support API SDK < 24 add the following line to your app `build.gradle` inside the `android` block:

```
defaultConfig {
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

If your minSdkVersion is 24 or higher, then your issue will be resolved on its own, because VectorDrawables have full support starting with this API.

See [Android Developers: Vector Drawables Backward Compatibility Solution](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution) for details.

Comment: But why is the issue coming up and is the above solution a quickfix or a good strategy ?

Comment: @Pranaysharma See [Android Developers: Vector Drawables Backward Compatibility Solution](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution) for details.

Comment: note: useSupportLibrary is wrong solution for me (min SDK 16, target 26), app crashes on start. I had have to remove this, remove @color from vectors and just search and replace all android:fillColor= pieces manually. It is very fast actually, take 10 seconds

Comment: Where do I add this line?

Comment: @Roymunson inside android key. Look at Wonil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52022896/465053) in this thread itself.

Comment: @mwa91 i stuck with this error form two hour and finally i solved thanks

Comment: This is work for me api sdk version 28. it is best soluiton for use.

Answer (score 15):

you need to use the hex code directly not referring to a resource.

```
<vector
  <path
    android:fillColor="#FFF"/></vector>
```

Comment: it is a regression version... if you want to change color, you are able to change one by one... it is easier to make a reference in color file and change it.

Comment: there unfortunately this is the only way to make your app works or you have to downgrade your gradle version

Comment: I too have the same issue. Why would a feature that was previously working fine be disabled? Is this maybe a bug?

Comment: I just updated to AS3 and got this issue, too. Why would that feature be removed?

Comment: no other solution beside injecting the color hex directly to the vector

Comment: This works as a workaround, but the "right" answer is @mwa91's answer to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Marty it never did work correctly. When generating png's, they would just become black instead of the color you marked in the SVG. They just made it an error now to prevent you from missing this issue

Comment: @Marty are you sure that the icons on android 4.x were not black, while they were the desired colors for 5 and up?

Answer (score 10):

Little bit more context for this error:

- Android 5.0 (API level 21) was the first version to officially support vector drawables.
- If you use minSdkVersion lower than 20, there are two solutions for vector drawable

  - Android Studio's Vector Asset Studio generate PNG. Please take a look [Android Studio document](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#apilevel). But, references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation.
  - Use support library
- Or, use 21 or above for minSdkVersion

For support library, add a statement to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

Comment: @MikeHanafey Could you please point out doc why minSdkVersion must be 24? Thanks.

Comment: The message below occurs unless minSdkVersion is increased to 24. I do not have an explanation, and found this by simply incrementing the value until the gradle build succeeded. Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while processing ./src/main/res/drawable/ic_selection_right_widen.xml : Can't process attribute android:fillColor="@color/kb_key_long_press_available": references to other resources are not supported by build-time PNG generation. See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html for details.

Comment: @MikeHanafey minSdkVersion must be 24 only if you use android:filltype, which sometimes the Android Vector Asset automatically puts in. Just get rid of it.

Comment: @Simone Thank you for the suggestion. That was the issue in my case.

Comment: default `fillType` is `nonZero` but it only differs from `evenOdd` in certain cases:
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty

Answer (score 5):

Do not use colorReference at fillColor attribute in Vector drawable just use hexa code

use like this

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#1abc9c"
    android:pathData="M9,11L7,11v2h2v-2zM13,11h-2v2h2v-2zM17,11h-2v2h2v-2zM19,4h-1L18,2h-2v2L8,4L8,2L6,2v2L5,4c-1.11,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2L3,20c0,1.1 0.89,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM19,20L5,20L5,9h14v11z"/>
```

instead of this

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:pathData="M9,11L7,11v2h2v-2zM13,11h-2v2h2v-2zM17,11h-2v2h2v-2zM19,4h-1L18,2h-2v2L8,4L8,2L6,2v2L5,4c-1.11,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2L3,20c0,1.1 0.89,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM19,20L5,20L5,9h14v11z"/>
```

Comment: This is a patch, I want to be able to re-theme my app without duplicating all drawables, also it's creating png instead of keeping vectorial. People should use @mwa91's solution.

Answer (score 4):

If your minSdkVersion is 21 you can disable the generation of PNG by adding this line:

```
// set to an empty list to disable the feature
vectorDrawables.generatedDensities = []
```

Removing this line will still generate the PNGs.

Source:
http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.VectorDrawablesOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to work around this by doing the following:

1. create a drawable-v21 folder and copy all your drawable xmls that use variables there
2. in the original drawable folder change all the icons to use a static color

This way the compiler will work

Comment: Yes, probably because API 21 supports Android 5.0 (Lollipop) which supports vector drawables natively. However, devices with earlier versions might then have no proper images at all: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `android:fillColor="@color/image_button_disabled"` this code for vector drawable.

```
// image_button_disabled.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/circular_image_color_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/circular_image_color_normal" />
</selector>
```

It's not supported.

Just replace it with `android:fillColor="#c4ca5e"`

Answer (score 0):

To add up to [@mwa91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3881869/mwa91) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47132142/3609514).

In case you need dynamic theming of drawable, but you don't have time to update your layouts and go with [@mwa91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3881869/mwa91) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47132142/3609514) and change all `android:src="@drawable/..."` attributes to `app:srcCompat="@drawable/..."`, you can always use hex color value in drawable and then later tint the drawable in ImageView:

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"
      android:tint="@color/image_button_disabled"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **filltype** and the warning will disappear. That's because:

> minSdkVersion must be 24 only if you use android:filltype

> The default fillType is nonZero but it only differs from evenOdd in certain cases

Make sure you don't need filltype, of course. In some cases it may affect the appearance of your vector drawable. You most likely don't need it if your icons are simple. It's sometimes added automatically, for instance when you import vector drawables from SVG.

Check this page for an explanation what it does [w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty](http://w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty)

Credit goes to @Simone and @hmac

---

A simple alternative is to use a color value directly, instead of using a color reference.

```
android:fillColor="#FF00AABB" // use this
android:fillColor="@color/image_button_disabled" // instead of this
```

Another alternative is settings this, but I'd rather avoid it:

```
defaultConfig {
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

The last resort alternative is to `increase your minSdkVersion to 24`.